# How to "collapse" rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So, if my current resultset is:

```
 Set  |  Label  |  Val
------------------------
  A   |  "LabA" |  NULL
  A   |  "LabA" |   1
  A   |  "LabB" |  NULL
  A   |  "LabB" |   2
  B   |  "LabA" |  NULL
  B   |  "LabA" |   3
  B   |  "LabC" |  NULL
```

What I really want is:

```
 Set  |  Label  |  Val
------------------------
  A   |  "LabA" |   1
  A   |  "LabB" |   2
  B   |  "LabA" |   3
  B   |  "LabC" |  NULL
```

How can I "collapse" the rows to get the desired resultset?

Comment: are you looking for the max value for set A and B per label? just use grouping http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Did you try with a "Group by Label" and then get the Max(Val) ?

Comment: Google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a [`MAX()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) aggregate with a [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) on the `Set` and `Label` columns:

```
Select  Set, Label, Max(Val) Val
From    YourTable
Group By Set, Label
Order By Set, Label
```